# Is there any way to simulate some GAE server error?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Are there ways to test my `error_handlers` setup in the `app.yaml` file, especially the error code `over_quota`?

Comment: Its always good to be specific. Could you show us what your `error_handlers` looks like?  What is it exactly, a module that you're routing through `app.yaml`?

Comment: as far as over quota goes you can easily delay to a separate project and run it into over quota mode

Comment: @mvanveen I was hoping to test the basic handler mentioned at [link](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Custom_Error_Responses) but it will be great if there is a way to test a general error_handler

Comment: @ShayErlichmen do you mean bombarding the app with requests, etc. to deplete its resources? Is there a more elegant solution, I wonder?

Comment: @Falcon maybe there is, but you should always test under real conditions (if possible). I don't know if the raise apiproxy_errors.OverQuotaError is 100% simulation accurate, maybe when there is a real over quote error other code kicks in.

Comment: @ShayErlichmen I agree. I will give it a try, at least for fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Testing `error_handlers`

`dev_appserver.py` is the application that is parsing your `app.yaml` and serving these error files.  This means that you're best bet is probably a straight up acceptance test where you bring up `dev_appserver.py` and try hitting it `localhost:8080` with `GETs` and `PUTs` that would trigger the various errors you're expecting.

So, if `/foo` returns a 404, you could do the following with [Python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html):

```
>>> def test_foo():
>>>   response = requests.get('/foo')
>>>   assert response.status_code == 404
```

#### Testing Over Quota Error

In this specific case it sounds like you're trying to explicitly raise the `over_quota` error.  [This link](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html) mentions that the exception you're looking for is `apiproxy_errors.OverQuotaError`.

I'm not sure what your test code is, but have you tried explicitly raising this error, with straight up `raise`?

I was able to run the following code after bootstrapping my `apiproxy_stub_map`, setting up my path, etc.:

```
from google.appengine.runtime import apiproxy_errors

def test_foo():
  raise apiproxy_errors.OverQuotaError
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is the flavor I want. So we can basically handle the error locally with `try...except` block. (It will be nice if there is a way to test the setup in `yaml` as I mentioned in the comment)

Comment: Could you be more specific?  I don't know what you mean by wanting "to test the setup in `yaml`."  Are you having trouble testing the endpoints you've defined in `app.yaml`?

Comment: Like in [this](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Custom_Error_Responses), we can setup static pages as `error_handlers` in `app.yaml`, I don't know how to test those (although the result might not be as interesting as those handled by `try...except`).

Comment: I think your best bet is an acceptance test through `dev_appserver.py`.  Your `app.yaml` is run through `dev_appserver.py` in order to route these errors properly, so I don't think you'd be able to test it with a bootstrapped testbed.  Alternatively, it's entirely possible to route errors through your actual WSGI application.  This would make automated testing way easier. **Edit**: Updated my answer to reflect your question better.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I think I finally understand how the errors are handled on GAE server. Actually the [official doc](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#When_a_Resource_is_Depleted) is quite clear: `HTTP 403` will be issued for **depleting quota on bandwidth** and (presumably, I will test this) will be handled by specified `error_handlers` in `app.yaml` (which only allow the very minimal response of a static page), i.e. this error will not get passed to the app. Only errors due to exceeding other quotas can be handled by the app.